# Why doesn't my parse function return return all expected tokens?

Tags: c, string, strtok

I wrote a program that reads a command line from the standard input, and pass it to a function that is supposed to parse it into tokens.

This is the parsing function:

```
char** parse_cmdline(char* cmdline) {
    char ** arr = malloc(10 * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i =0 ; i < 10; ++i)
        arr[i] = malloc(30 * sizeof(char));
    char * token = strtok(cmdline, " ");
    int i = 0;
    while(token != NULL) {
        if(i > 9) arr = realloc(arr, (i+10)*sizeof(char*) );
        arr[i] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }
    printf("flag1");
    return arr;
}
```

And this is how I am using it it `main()`:

```
int main() {
    int status;
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();

    while(1) {      
        if(pid < 0) {
            status = -1;
            perror("Fork");
        } else if(pid == 0) {
            char* cmd;
            printf("$");
            if(fgets(cmd, sizeof cmd, stdin) == NULL) break;
            parse_cmdline(cmd);
        } else {
            if( waitpid(pid, &status, 0) != pid ) {
                status = -1;
            }
            break;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

This is an example of input that I supply to my program:

```
ls l a
```

The expected output should be:

```
l
```

(that is, the second argument, printed by my parse function)

And literally nothing happens. Not even the printf("flag1"); prints. But if I remove the `char ** commands` and put the `printf("%s", commands[0]);` in the parse_cmdline function, everything works, except im not assigning the return. Why and how to fix it?

---

As requested, here's the entirety of my code:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

char** parse_cmdline(char* cmdline) {
    char ** arr = malloc(10 * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i =0 ; i < 10; ++i)
        arr[i] = malloc(30 * sizeof(char));
    char * token = strtok(cmdline, " ");
    int i = 0;
    while(token != NULL) {
        if(i > 9) arr = realloc(arr, (i+10)*sizeof(char*) );
        arr[i] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", arr[1]);
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Post a minimal, complete, verifiable example.

Comment: What more do you need?

Comment: Something I can paste into a file and compile, plus an input I can pipe to the result of the compilation. Possibly an output I can compare the output of the program's run with.

Comment: To start with, `break` doesn't work outside a `for` or `while` loop. So if this code really compiles, there is stuff missing.

Comment: I edited it, added the full code.

Comment: You are not allocating room for the string.

Comment: Undefined behavior for using the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part looks strange - see comments inline:

```
char ** arr = malloc(10 * sizeof(char*));
for (int i =0 ; i < 10; ++i)
    arr[i] = malloc(30 * sizeof(char));     // Here you allocate memory
                                            // for holding a part of the command

char * token = strtok(cmdline, " ");
int i = 0;
while(token != NULL) {
    if(i > 9) arr = realloc(arr, (i+10)*sizeof(char*) );

    arr[i] = token;             // But here you overwrite the pointer value and
                                // and thereby create a memory leak

    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    i++;
}
```

Perhaps you wanted to do a string copy instead - like:

```
strcpy(arr[i], token);   // Instead of arr[i] = token;
```

Further this line seems strange:

```
if(i > 9) arr = realloc(arr, (i+10)*sizeof(char*) );
```

You increase `arr` so that it can hold more `char*` but this time you don't allocate memory for the new strings as you did initially.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not allocating room for the command. Change the declaration of `cmd` to something like this:

```
char cmd[100];
```

Not allocating memory causes undefined behavior, and this (as well with proper usage of `fgets` fixes that). But you should also check from `fgets()` if 100 characters were enough:

```
if (strstr(cmd, "\n") == NULL) {
    /* the user typed more than 100 characters */
}
```

Because if they were not enough, then you are going to parse an incomplete command line and, the next time your loop iterates over the input data, it will parse more incomplete commands.

Finally, `strtok` returns pointers to the tokens **in** `cmd`, so all those characters array you allocated at the beginning of your parse function were memory leaks, because you replaced them with pointers from  `strtok` inside the loop:

```
arr[i] = token;
/* this throws away the address of the 10-character array you allocated
 * at the beginning of the function. You can't free() that memory
 * anymore. Your program is "leaking" memory. */
```

Strictly speaking, by the way, you should be checking if `realloc` is returning a valid address or `NULL`. `malloc` too. It is unlikely that you'll have problems with this in such a small program, but it's the right practice.

You should also dispose of the parsed commands once you have used them. You allocate an array of pointers with both `malloc` and `realloc`, but you never  `free` them in your program. Even though the program ends soon, while the program is running, that's memory leak. (Again, unlikely you'll see problems with a small program, but it's good practice.)